# Programming notepad - opening new file using Java

Tags: java

At first, sorry for my bad english, it is not my primairy language

I'm making a notepad copy, but i need help by open a new file. What i've got is:

You can open a new file, but when you open it, the old texts you've already written won't remove.

My question is of someone can help me to code a openfile script i can use.
My requirement:
- i want when you open a new file, he ask me you save it or not.
- and when i open a file the old texts is removed and replaced with the new one.

Thanks and advance,

Comment: Did you look at all the java samples? There is a rich text editor sample in java sample code. That will give you ideas of how to implement the notepad in Java.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly -

While writing the file open the output stream using `FileOutputStream(File file, boolean append)` and pass the append - false, then bytes will be written from the beginning of the file rather than the end.

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file,false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend that you invest some time reading about I/O Java concepts, here are some cool resources:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html
- http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/0596009208/14dot-serialization-and-file-i-o-saving-objects/serialization_and_file_i_solidus_o_colon

If you want a step-by-step guide, there are plenty of tutorials on how to create a simple text editor in Java, e.g., http://book.javanb.com/sillsoft-Press-Java-instantcode-developing-applications-using-java-nio/LiB0031.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use a FileWriter or a FileOutputStream like this:

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("FileName.txt",false)
pw.print(What ever data you want to write into the file);
```

Just note that the boolean false-will make the file writing at the beginning of the file no matter what the previous content is.